# auto_increment id with unique key?

Tags: mysql

I have a unique key hashtag and a auto_increment id.

when one user send a duplicate hashtag it will not be inserted but the id will increase.

eg:

```
5 amazing 
1 cool 
8 do 
3 nice
```

notice that one user sends `cool` and another send `cool` after it, so I haven't id 2. why?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hashtags` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hashtag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `hashtag` (`hashtag`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: It would seem that the database engine is reserving the identifier before committing the change.  Since the new record is invalid (violates a unique constraint), it isn't committed.  This seems like correct behavior, since you don't want it to commit a non-unique value in that column.

Comment: InnoDB does this, MyISAM doesn't.

Comment: thank you friends! no way that I can insert keeping the numbers in order, without jump any?

Answer (score 1):

It is a "normal" behavior caused by the execution order built in to InnoDB engine. Might be implemented in this way for speeding up the execution. When you use auto increment, there is some kind of model that stores the next available index (id) for a table. So inserting item with [insert clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) the engine first asks the next available index (id) from that model, that also increments the value so it is ready for the next guy who wants the next id. So when implemented in this way, the model does not care whether the insert clause execution succeeded or not.

Comment: Explicit transaction wouldn't change this behaviour